# Does Openlink Virtuoso provide a simple read-only SPARQL query page out of the box?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I'm wondering if Virtuoso has any built in features or packages that would let me expose a simple page where people can enter read-only SPARQL queries?

(sort of like this:  http://dbpedia.org/snorql/)

I know if you log into conductor, there is a page to do this, but i'd like to provide a public access page that doesn't require logging in

Comment: you don't have to log in when using the web query interface, usually located at `http://host:port/sparql` - conductor is a different thing.

Comment: thank you.  Does this page restrict queries to read only operations only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtuoso's built-in, read-only, no-login, default SPARQL query page is found at `http://<cname>[:<port>]/sparql` -- as at http://dbpedia.org/sparql (a/k/a http://dbpedia.org:80/sparql]).   (Note — configuration *can* be adjusted, such that this default `/sparql` endpoint is read-write; such adjustment is not the default setup.)

(The http://dbpedia.org/snorql page is specific to the DBpedia deployment; this is not part of the default Virtuoso kit.)

There's [a lot of documentation](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideSPARQLEndpoints) on the various built-in protected pages which themselves may be set up as read-only or read-write.  These include --

- `http://<cname>[:<port>]/sparql-auth`
- `http://<cname>[:<port>]/sparql-oauth`
- `https://<cname>[:<port>]/sparql`
- `https://<cname>[:<port>]/sparql-webid`
- `http://<cname>[:<port>]/sparql-graph-crud`
- `http://<cname>[:<port>]/sparql-graph-crud-auth`

Answer (score 1):

Read-Only is the default mode of any SPARQL Query Service endpoint associated with a newly instantiated Virtuoso instance.

If you want Read-Write access e.g., an ability to use SPARQL with Insert, Delete, and Drop (or Clear) Graph operations, you will need to use the "sparql-auth" endpoint or enable Access Controls on the standard endpoint.